# retrofit spring boot not responding

Tags: spring, jpa, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a server in spring boot, which is running on port 8080.

Now I'm trying to call rest api in my android application using retrofit2.

Here is what I have implemented:

```
        final TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.t1);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);

        Call<TC> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getPosts();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<TC>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TC> call, Response<TC> response) {
                textView.setText(response.toString());

                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    return;
                }

                TC posts = response.body();
                textView.setText(posts.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TC> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

I can surly say that, it's not working as my api is not even being called. As the hello world screen remains as it is.

And in my server I have logger, which doesn't log anything, so it doesn't get called.

Here is my CORS:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry
                        .addMapping("*")
                        .allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Do not ignore error messages you receive inside `onFailure()` method of Retrofit. Please log the error response `Log.e("ERROR", t);` and [edit] the question post error messages/stack trace here.

Comment: i resolved the problem, check out my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the word `localhost`.

As for debugging purpose I'm connecting the android device with my PC so my android device can't connect to `localhost` as it is just an alias of my IP address.

[image: localhost equivalent]

To resolve this, I opened up CMD and wrote `ipconfig`, by this command I can see all details related to IP.

And here it shows my IPv4 address as `$.$.$.$`. I just replaced the `localhost` with that `$.$.$.$`. 
Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Any ideas how to make it work with Asp.net core. I just test it wih my local machine ip address and work perfectly.

Unfortunately, not the case with Asp.net core.

[aAndroid + Retrofit + Asp.net API "java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69069156/aandroid-retrofit-asp-net-api-java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexception)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.